# react navigation route states to have key and index

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I have not been able to generate the state correctly using either from `NavigationActions.init()` or from the the one mentioned in the docs. 
This is how my navigators are defined:

```
const HomeNav = TabNavigator({
feed:{screen:Feed},
restaurantScreen:{screen:Restaurant},
},{
tabBarComponent:NavigationComponent,
tabBarPosition:'bottom',
tabBarOptions:{
    bottomNavigationOptions:{
        labelColor:'white',
        rippleColor:'white',
        tabs:{
            feed:{
                barBackgroundColor:'#37474F',
            },
            restaurantScreen:{
                barBackgroundColor:'#00796B',
            }
        }
    }
}
});
export const Navigator=StackNavigator(
{
    HomeScreen:{screen:Home},
    VerifyScreen:{screen:Verify},
    newUserScreen1:{screen:newUser1},
    newUserScreen2:{screen:newUser2},
    loginScreen:{screen:login},
    feedScreen:{screen:HomeNav},
},
{
    headerMode:'none',
},
);
```

And this is how I am setting my initial state:

```
const initialState=Navigator.router.getStateForAction(
NavigationActions.init()
);

function navigate(screenName,state){
return Navigator.router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.navigate({routeName:screenName},state));
}
```

The following error shows up:
`Expect nav state to have routes and index,{routeName:'feedScreen',key:...}` When navigating to feed tab navigator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second code snippet it should be like this:

```
const initialState=Navigator.router.getStateForAction(
NavigationActions.init()
);

function navigate(screenName,state){
return Navigator.router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.navigate({routeName:screenName}),state); 
}
```

- `getStateForAction` receives a second "state" parameter, you were instead passing it to `NavigationActions.navigate`.
- `NavigationActions.init()` expects any object like {routeName:'screen1'} as an parameter to initialise state. So it should be something like this: `NavigationActions.init({routeName:'screen1'})`.